# dict comprehension with multiple output

Tags: python, performance, dictionary-comprehension

I'd like to fill two dicts simultaneously, like in this example:

```
def square(num):
    return(num*num,num+num)
    
square_dict={}
sum_dict={}
for i in range(1,11):
    square_dict[i],sum_dict[i]=square(i)


print(square_dict)
print(sum_dict)
```

and I'm wondering if it would be possible to do it with dict comprehension. Something like:

`square_dict, sum_dict=  [dict(zip(num, square(num)) for num in range(1, 11))]`

(which is obviousely not working)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For all practical purposes, I'd just use your current approach, or if you prefer a dict-comp, store the tuples in a list first, and then use two separate dict-comp taking the 1st and 2nd value from those tuples respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can zip the key-value pairs from the output of `square` for each item in `range(1, 11)` so that you can map the two resulting sequences to the dict constructor:

```
square_dict, sum_dict = map(dict, (zip(*([(i, v) for v in square(i)] for i in range(1, 11)))))
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/AdventurousDeficientMathematics

Another approach is to zip the output of `square` into two sequences of squares and sums, and then zip `range(1, 11)` with each sequence into key-value pairs for dict construction:

```
square_dict, sum_dict = (dict(zip(range(1, 11), p)) for p in zip(*map(square, range(1, 11))))
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/KindSafeMethods